# Medium Rss feed is not parsing in wordpress

Tags: rss

Here is my code my code

I need to add 'medium' rss feed in my wordpress site
but it shows the error 
and i added the image here[image]

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<rss version="2.0">


<h2><?php _e( 'Recent news from Some-Other Blog:', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></h2>

    <?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
    include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );
    // Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
    $rss = fetch_feed( 'https://medium.com/feed/krishnan' );

    var_dump($rss);

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly
        // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5.

        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 ); 
        // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
        $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );
    endif;
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
            <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
            <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                        title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>
<!-- .content-area -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please use the [`edit` link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/266199/edit) above ( and below your question ) to add more detail about your issue, what you've tried to do to solve this issue, and any other information that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for rss link but its not working, help me to find the solution

```
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );
// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'https://medium.com/feed/......' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly
    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5.

    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 ); 
    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );
endif;
?>
```